# Markdown記法で見出しの次の行を空ける目的

Tags: markdown

巷で見かけるREADME.mdは以下のようにして、
見出しの次の行を空白にしているものが多いようです。

```
git + hub = github
==================

hub is a command line tool ...
```

GitHubとBitbucketでしか試していないのですが、
この空白行は設けずとも表示は正しくされるように思います。
この空白行を入れる目的は何でしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[本家Markdownのドキュメント](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#header) では

> Setext-style headers are “underlined” using equal signs (for first-level headers) and dashes (for second-level headers).

としか書かれていませんし、そこで配布されている Perl スクリプトでも `^(.+)[ \t]*\n=+[ \t]*\n+` と連続した空行を無視するように書かれていますから、必須というわけではありません。

とはいえ空行を入れないと、ただの区切り線に見えそうですし

```
これは見出しだけど
================
これは本文なんです
```

[GitHub Flavored Markdown](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown/#tables) などの方言で使われるテーブル記法と紛らわしいですし

```
First Header  | Second Header
------------- | -------------
Content Cell  | Content Cell
Content Cell  | Content Cell
```

その辺を考えると、やっぱり空行を入れる形に落ち着くのかなと思います。

Comment: 本家Markdownのドキュメントにある下線付きという表現はいいですね。
確かに下線として見ると読みやすいように感じます。

Answer (score 1):

テキストで見た時に見やすくするためじゃないかな。

テキストで見ても違和感ないのがMarkdown記法のいいところだし。